# Как получить позицию курсора от начала строки textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например курсор установлен в позицию 87 textarea.
А как получить позицию не от начала textarea , а от начала строки в которой он установлен ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот мой вариант:

```js
function getCaret(el) { 
  if (el.selectionStart) { 
    return el.selectionStart; 
  } else if (document.selection) { 
    el.focus(); 
 
    var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
    if (r == null) { 
      return 0; 
    } 
 
    var re = el.createTextRange(), 
        rc = re.duplicate(); 
    re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark()); 
    rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re); 
 
    return rc.text.length; 
  }  
  return 0; 
}
function getPosInRow(el) {
    var caret = getCaret(el);
    var text = el.value.substr(0, caret).replace(/^(.*[\n\r])*([^\n\r]*)$/, '$2');
    
    console.log(text);
    return text.length;
}

document.getElementById('thetext').onkeyup = function(e) {
 document.getElementById('result').value = getPosInRow(document.getElementById('thetext'));
    return true;
};
```

```css
#thetext {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-text">
    <textarea id="thetext">Это текст, позицию которого можно получить.</textarea><br>
    <div>Позиция в строке: <input id="result" size="4"></div>
</div>
```

Функция **getCaret()** взята на просторах интернета и вычисляет положение каретки в `textarea`.

Функция **getPosInRow()** вычисляет позицию каретки в строке на основании функции `getCaret()` таким образом: текст из `textarea` обрезается после каретки, затем с помощью регулярки в нем оставляется последняя строка и потом вычисляется длина этой строки.

**P.S.**

Пример на чистом js, можете сами его в jquery доработать.

Comment: Попробуйте поперемещать курсор по тексту. Позиция в строке остаётся неизменной :( Вы вычисляете позицию каретки, а курсор и каретка это не одно и то же.

Comment: @Taypfoon, что в вашем понимании есть курсор? Курсор мыши? Откуда вы получили число 87 для курсора?

Comment: Курсор - указатель позиции мыши на экране. 
В textarea каретку можно перемещать по тексту кликом левой кнопкой мыши. 
Хочется получить позицию курсора ( перемещённой каретки ) по клику. Позицию 87 я получил функцией getCaret().

Comment: @Taypfoon, так после клика по `textarea` вызовите не `getCaret()`, а `getPosInRow()`, которую я вам в ответе дал. В чем проблема?

Comment: Да, простите, я тормознул. Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Фокус элемента может создать сайд эффект в библиотеке, управляющей состоянием формы, поэтому, предлагаю следующую функцию подобную чистой

```js
const getCaretPos = (element: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement) => {
    return element.selectionStart || element.value.length;
};
```

Чтобы получить актуальное состояние, подпишитесь на событие `click` у `input` или `textarea`, вызывайте функция мануально в коллбеке `onChange`