# Как выбрать текст в textarea до каретки

Tags: javascript

Задача заключается в том, что б создать новую строку при нажатие Enter + Ctrl или Enter + Alt(Правый и левый)
Вот код

```
$(this.$textBox).on('keyup change', function (e) {
        if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
            _this.$textBox.val(_this.$textBox.val() + '\n');
        }
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
            _this.$textBox.val(_this.$textBox.val() + '\n');
        }
    });
```

Вроде работает, но баг в том, что если я захочу вернуться в середину сообщение и создать новый абзац, а мне при таком коде добавится просто новая строка внизу, а не в середине. При Shift+Enter код работает как надо и как видите по  коду я эту комбинацию не определил. Как указать что б также как для Shift + Enter делался абзац начиная от каретки а не просто пушить новую строку?

Comment: Вам нужно вставлять \n не в конец полученной строки, а разрезать строку в том месте, где находится каретка ввода и вставить между этими частями \n, тогда будет работать.

Comment: а каким образом вставить именно в середину, т.е. как определить где каретка?

Comment: например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/463338/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-textarea

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел вот тут  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968174/set-text-cursor-position-in-a-textarea

Но добавил немного своего. Запретил Shift + Enter комбинацию т.к. она идет по дефолту переноса и выходит два абзаца.  Добавил сохранение курсора на место нового абзаца.

```
$(this.$textBox).on('keyup change', function (e) {
        if (((e.wich && e.wich === 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode === 13)) && (!e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 13)) {
            var sentence = $(this).val();
            var position = $(this).get(0).selectionStart;
            var length = sentence.length;
            var before = sentence.substr(0, position);
            var after = sentence.substr(position, length);
            _this.$textBox.val(before + "\n" + after);
            $(this).get(0).selectionEnd = position + 1;
            if (_this.$textBox.val() === '\n') {
                _this.$textBox.val('');
            }
        }
    });
```